# Which movie is this supposed 'Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind' quote really from?

Tags: identify-this-movie, dialogue, eternal-sunshine-of-spotless-mind

The following quote is mentioned all over the internet that it's from *Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind*.

> "We met at the wrong time. That's what I keep telling myself anyway. Maybe one day years from now, we'll meet in a coffee shop in a far away city somewhere and we could give it another shot. So until then, I'll just have to continue feeling this way everyday. Sad."

I just saw the movie, it doesn't appear anywhere in the film. I even searched through subtitle files. Was there a deleted scene or something in the film where this line is spoken? Or is it simply from a different film? If yes, which one?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1ovjtx/tomt_we_met_at_the_wrong_time_thats_what_i_keep/

Comment: It is probably not, but reminds me of Before Sunrise trilogy. How they met years later in another city. :d

Comment: I've a feeling I know this quote, and I haven't seen _Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless Mind_ (yet). I'm wondering about _Californication_.

Comment: Is it maybe the John Cusack movie Serendipity?

Comment: The Reddit thread I linked to appears to explore, then reject that Serendipity (which I have never seen).

Comment: It seems more and more likely that this is some anonymous quote\tweet\tumblr post that was mistaken for an *Eternal Sunshine* quote along the way and went viral.

Comment: But it's so familiar, of some movie.. Sigh

Answer (score 4):

It's not from Eternal Sunshine, you are correct there.    It's not found in the 1st or shooting draft (available on [Charlie Kaufman's website](http://www.beingcharliekaufman.com/index.php/scripts-writing/scripts-writing/film-scripts)).

The debate raged a couple years ago on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/1ovjtx/tomt_we_met_at_the_wrong_time_thats_what_i_keep/) to no definitive answer.

Attributions to the film are everywhere, which goes to show that you shouldn't believe everything you read on the internet.

Comment: If something is stated on the Internet and has a famous name next to it, it must be true - Thomas Jefferson, 1770

Comment: This is an interesting comment, but it's not an answer to what movie is it.

Comment: Well, technically he only asked if it's from this or another film.  So...

Comment: Sorry I thought that was implicit, I've added to the question.